# "Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found" after Spring Boot Upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I get this exception message after upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.5 to 2.2.2, when I try to start the Application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'feignContract' defined in org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'feignContract' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignConversionService' defined in org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'feignConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.get(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.feign(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:262)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171)
    ... 169 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignConversionService' defined in org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'feignConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 189 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'feignConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 203 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1054)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1038)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1088)
    at at.porscheinformatik.retail.integration.api.formatter.DefaultDateTimeFormatter.<init>(DefaultDateTimeFormatter.java:24)
    at at.porscheinformatik.sbo.integration.impl.rest.feign.RestIntegrationFeignConfiguration.registerFormatters(RestIntegrationFeignConfiguration.java:30)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsConfiguration.feignConversionService(FeignClientsConfiguration.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

When I just upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.1, this exception doesn't occur.

After adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

it works for 2.2.2.

So my question is, why do I suddenly need to manually add a dependency after this Spring Boot upgrade.

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` with both versions of Spring Boot and compare the results for `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`. My guess is one of the Sprint Boot dependencies got updated (which internally might have removed  `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`) in version `2.2.2`, requiring you to explicitly add it.

Comment: I already tried this, but there is no `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` dependency in the tree for both versions.

Comment: @AlexanderDo what is the java version you are using?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne It's AdoptOpenJDK Version 8.0.232.09

Answer (score 1):

I would look at your dependencies which might use xml as configuration. I am using Spring Boot 2.3.1 and did not need this dependency until I added Liquibase support. Since I was using xml for the Liquibase configuration then I see same error at startup. Once I added this dependency then error went away.

Comment: I confirm that the same issue occurred to me during support of Liquibase within Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE and issue disappeared after adding jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application is using / including Liquibase, this occurs because of an erroneous file in liquibase-core which is defining an SPI extension for a Jackson module but not providing the implementation for that module: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1051

The workaround listed in the OP is sufficient, as its providing the implementation to the Jackson module referenced in the SPI file, but you can also upgrade Liquibase to >= 3.10.1 to resolve this (I only tested 3.10.3 but according to the linked defect 3.10.1 should work)

For Gradle, the dependency is:

```
implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.10.3'
```

More info: https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/387#issuecomment-581603444

Comment: In fact I am using Liquibase, so I will have a look on that issue. 
I will post an answer if the workaround works.
Thanks!

Comment: You should also be able to downgrade liquibase to `3.8.0` if you want to stay within the `3.8.x` release train.