# ERROR: column is of type json but expression is of type character varying in Hibernate

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I need to map two columns of entity class as json in postgres using spring data jpa. After reading multiple stackoverflow posts and baeldung post ,

[How to map a map JSON column to Java Object with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738569/how-to-map-a-map-json-column-to-java-object-with-jpa)

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object

I did configuration as below. However, I am facing error "**ERROR: column "headers" is of type json but expression is of type character varying**"

Please provide some pointer to resolve this issue.

I have an entity class as below

```
@Entity
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String url;
    private String httpMethod;

    @Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Map<String, String> headers;

    @Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Map<String, String> urlVariables;
}
```

I have created a test class to test if entity is persisted or not. On running this junit, below test case is failing with error as below

[image]

```
@SpringBootTest
class TaskRepositoryTest {

    private static Task randomTask = randomTask();

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        taskRepository.deleteAll();
        taskRepository.save(randomTask);
    }

    public static Task randomTask() {
        return randomTaskBuilder().build();
    }

    public static TaskBuilder randomTaskBuilder() {
        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(randomAlphanumericString(10),randomAlphanumericString(10));

        Map<String,String> urlVariables = new HashMap<>();
        urlVariables.put(randomAlphanumericString(10),randomAlphanumericString(10));

        return builder()
                .id(randomPositiveInteger())
                .httpMethod(randomAlphanumericString(10))
                .headers(headers)
                .urlVariables(urlVariables)
                .url(randomAlphanumericString(10)));
    }
}
```

Using liquibase, I have created table in postgres DB and I could see column datatype as json.

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: abc
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: task
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: int
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
              - column:
                  name: url
                  type: varchar(250)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                    unique: true
              - column:
                  name: http_method
                  type: varchar(50)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: headers
                  type: json
              - column:
                  name: url_variables
                  type: json
      rollback:
        - dropTable:
            tableName: task
```

Comment: This looks like a string, not json:         headers.put(randomAlphanumericString(10),randomAlphanumericString(10));

Comment: @Frank Heikens yes this is map but HashMapConverter.class should convert entity attribute to json before writing to DB.

Comment: In the tutorial you've mentioned `Map<String, Object>` is used, while you use `Map<String, String>`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Because my requirement is of Map<String,String> and not Map<String,Object>

Comment: @user2800089 then you should adjust HashMapConverter to deal with `Map<String,String>`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko My HMC implements proper interface as below: public class HashMapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String>

Let me know what other adjustment is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Above configuration did not work.

Hence, I followed below link to solve the use-case

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

["Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found" after Spring Boot Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933277/provider-com-fasterxml-jackson-module-jaxb-jaxbannotationmodule-not-found-afte)

Added additional dependencies in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Removed HashMapConverter configuration and made below changes in entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String url;
    private String httpMethod;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Map<String, String> headers;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Map<String, String> urlVariables;
}
```

After these changes, TaskRepositoryTest passed.

Comment: for me using some unknown lib looks quite bad and not possible on a lot of projects :)

Answer (score 15):

For anyone who landed here because they're using `JdbcTemplate` and getting this error, the solution is very simple: In your SQL statement, cast the JSON argument using `::jsonb` or CAST.

E.g. `String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO xxx (id, json_column) VALUES(?, ?)";`

becomes `String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO xxx (id, json_column) VALUES(?, ?::jsonb)";`

or with named params `String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO xxx (id, json_column) VALUES(:id, CAST(:json_column AS JSONB))";`

Comment: thanks @spork, it's working

Comment: worked for me too

Comment: The question was about Hibernate...

Comment: @snorbi It's almost like error messages can be related to different things....

Comment: Thank you for this -- this is the exact problem I was running into, trying to perform inserts using raw JDBC into a jsonb column.

Answer (score 15):

Alternative solution using `org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer`

Sample entity

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer;

@Entity
@Table
public class SomeEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "some_class", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  @Convert(converter = SomeClassConvertor.class)
  @ColumnTransformer(write = "?::jsonb")
  private SomeClass someClass;
}
```

Sample converter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.airtel.africa.entity.SomeClass;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class SomeClassConvertor implements AttributeConverter<SomeClass, String> {
  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(SomeClass someClass) {
    String someClassJson = null;
    try {
      someClassJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someClass);
    } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
      log.error("JSON writing error", e);
    }

    return someClassJson;
  }

  @Override
  public SomeClass convertToEntityAttribute(String someClassJSON) {
    SomeClass someClass = null;
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(someClassJSON)) {
      return someClass;
    }
    try {
      someClass = objectMapper.readValue(someClassJSON, someClass.class);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      log.error("JSON reading error", e);
    }
    return someClass;
  }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a legend. 
I was missing this one:  @ColumnTransformer(write = "?::jsonb")
And adding it it worked perfect. thank you...

Comment: you're the man. I was missing the casting

Comment: thanks for pointing out the @ColumnTransformer! I was about to fall back on a native query because I couldn't get the mapping right

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when I migrated my projects from MySQL 8.0.21 to Postgres 13. My project uses Spring boot with the Hibernate types dependency version 2.7.1. In my case the solution was simple.

[image]

All I needed to do was change that and it worked.

Referenced from the [Hibernate Types Documentation page](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types).

Answer (score 3):

(for posterity) There is an alternative solution, not totally safe (automatic cast from/to string), but should be just fine for non-critical or data/structures you control:

add ?stringtype=unspecified to your postgresql connectionstring:

for example:
(in your application.yml)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname?stringtype=unspecified
```

this will make postgresql try to cast your string to json automatically.
No need for any extra imports or @type definitions or custom sql-queries, the example as in the question is all you need:

```
@Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
private Map<String, String> headers;
```

PPS: I have not tried this with jsonb or other databasevendors.

Comment: Also applicable for postgresql db